# Why does my model creation timeout when run in jest but works fine from the server?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm learning how to use jest and have a very simple route I'm trying to test, that builds a small payload and creates a model, persisting to mysql.

````
describe('Validation Routes', function () {
        beforeAll(async () => {
            await db.sequelize.sync({ force: true })
        })
            
        test('responds to /createValidationField', async () => {
            let payload = validationBody;
            const res = await request(app)
                .post('/api/validations/createValidationField')
                .send(payload);
                //.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //expect(res.header['content-type']).toBe('application/json; charset=utf-8');
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
        });
    });```
````

This always results in

```
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 30000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      12 |     })
      13 |
    > 14 |     test('responds to /createValidationField', async () => {
         |     ^
```

But if I make the request with the server running, the result is as expected.

Inside of the controller:

```
ValidationField.create(validationField)
     .then(data => {
         res.status(200).send({message: 'Validation Field creation successful: ' + data.id});
     })
     .catch(err => {
         res.status(500).send({
             message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Validation Field."
         });
     });
```

Interestingly, the model is making it to the database, even when the test itself timesout. I'm not sure why ValidationField.create would never return anything, the context of a test. Has anyone run into this before?

I'm using express 4.18.2, jest 29.3.1, supertest 6.3.3

Comment: Does the API return anything? Can you debug it?

Comment: @LinDu it never returns anything even tho the data has persisted . A normal api call does result in a returned response

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show the code of the API controller.

Comment: @LinDu it's already there